Converting multiple columns to rows using UNPIVOT
I am a beginner SQL user. I wrote a query to extract several Fuel emissions columns and wrote a display message to show if it meets the requirements (Previous emission - Fuel Emission = Fuel consumption). This resulted in many columns based on the 8 different fuel types and Google suggested using UNPIVOT. I want to convert the many columns to just Fuel Type, Previous Emission, Fuel Emission, Fuel Consumption, and Message (which I call Miscellaneous here).
The following is my attempt:
With FuelCheckResults AS (
select *,
    case
        when t3.total_HSFO_emission is null or t3.previous_HFO_emission is null or t3.total_HFO is null then 'NULL VALUE ERROR'
        when t3.previous_HFO_emission - t3.total_HSFO_emission = t3.total_HFO then 'valid'
        else CONCAT('not valid emission, ', 'previous HFO emission: ', FORMAT(t3.previous_HFO_emission,'N2'), '; total HFO: ', FORMAT(t3.total_HFO,'N2'), '; total HSFO emission: ', FORMAT(t3.total_HSFO_emission,'N2'),'; Variance in HSFO emission ', FORMAT((t3.previous_HFO_emission - t3.total_HSFO_emission -  t3.total_HFO),'N2') )
    end as fuel_HSFO_emission_check,
    case
        when t3.total_LSFO_emission is null or t3.previous_LSFO_emission is null or t3.total_LSFO is null then 'NULL VALUE ERROR'
        when t3.previous_LSFO_emission - t3.total_LSFO_emission = t3.total_LSFO then 'valid'
        else CONCAT('not valid emission, ', 'previous LSFO emission: ', FORMAT(t3.previous_LSFO_emission,'N2'), '; total LSFO: ', FORMAT(t3.total_LSFO,'N2'), '; total LSFO emission: ', FORMAT(t3.total_LSFO_emission,'N2'), '; Variance in LSFO emission ', FORMAT((t3.previous_LSFO_emission - t3.total_LSFO_emission  - t3.total_LSFO),'N2'))
    end as fuel_LSFO_emission_check,
    case
        when t3.total_VLSFO_emission is null or t3.previous_VLSFO_emission is null or t3.total_VLSFO is null then 'NULL VALUE ERROR'
        when t3.previous_VLSFO_emission - t3.total_VLSFO_emission = t3.total_VLSFO then 'valid'
        else CONCAT('not valid emission, ', 'previous VLSFO emission: ', FORMAT(t3.previous_VLSFO_emission,'N2'), '; total VLSFO: ', FORMAT(t3.total_VLSFO,'N2'), '; total VLSFO emission: ', FORMAT(t3.total_VLSFO_emission,'N2'), '; Variance in VLSFO emission ', FORMAT(( t3.previous_VLSFO_emission - t3.total_VLSFO_emission - t3.total_VLSFO),'N2'))
    end as fuel_VLSFO_emission_check,
    case
        when t3.total_MGO_emission is null or t3.previous_MGO_emission is null or t3.total_MGO is null then 'NULL VALUE ERROR'
        when t3.previous_MGO_emission - t3.total_MGO_emission = t3.total_MGO then 'valid'
        else CONCAT('not valid emission, ', 'previous MGO emission: ', FORMAT(t3.previous_MGO_emission,'N2'), '; total MGO: ', FORMAT(t3.total_MGO,'N2'), '; total MGO emission: ', FORMAT(t3.total_MGO_emission,'N2'), '; Variance in MGO emission ', FORMAT((t3.previous_MGO_emission - t3.total_MGO_emission - t3.total_MGO),'N2'))
    end as fuel_MGO_emission_check,
    case
        when t3.total_MDO_emission is null or t3.previous_MDO_emission is null or t3.total_MDO is null then 'NULL VALUE ERROR'
        when t3.previous_MDO_emission - t3.total_MDO_emission = t3.total_MDO then 'valid'
        else CONCAT('not valid emission, ', 'previous MDO emission: ', FORMAT(t3.previous_MDO_emission,'N2'), '; total MDO: ', FORMAT(t3.total_MDO,'N2'), '; total MDO emission: ', FORMAT(t3.total_MDO_emission,'N2'), '; Variance in MDO emission ', FORMAT((t3.previous_MDO_emission - t3.total_MDO_emission - t3.total_MDO),'N2'))
    end as fuel_MDO_emission_check,
    case
        when t3.total_co2_emission is null or t3.previous_co2_emission is null or t3.total_co2 is null then 'NULL VALUE ERROR'
        when t3.previous_co2_emission - t3.total_co2_emission = t3.total_co2 then 'valid'
        else CONCAT('not valid emission, ', 'previous co2 emission: ', FORMAT(t3.previous_co2_emission,'N2'), '; total co2: ', FORMAT(t3.total_co2,'N2'), '; total co2 emission: ', FORMAT(t3.total_co2_emission,'N2'), '; Variance in co2 emission ', FORMAT((t3.previous_co2_emission - t3.total_co2_emission - t3.total_co2),'N2'))
    end as fuel_co2_emission_check,
    case
        when t3.total_no2_emission is null or t3.previous_no2_emission is null or t3.total_no2 is null then 'NULL VALUE ERROR'
        when t3.previous_no2_emission - t3.total_no2_emission = t3.total_no2 then 'valid'
        else CONCAT('not valid emission, ', 'previous no2 emission: ', FORMAT(t3.previous_no2_emission,'N2'), '; total no2: ', FORMAT(t3.total_no2,'N2'), '; total no2 emission: ', FORMAT(t3.total_no2_emission,'N2'), '; Variance in no2 emission ', FORMAT((t3.previous_no2_emission - t3.total_no2_emission - t3.total_no2),'N2'))
    end as fuel_no2_emission_check,
    case
        when t3.total_LNG_emission is null or t3.previous_LNG_emission is null or t3.total_LNG is null then 'NULL VALUE ERROR'
        when t3.previous_LNG_emission - t3.total_LNG_emission = t3.total_LNG then 'valid'
        else CONCAT('not valid emission, ', 'previous LNG emission: ', FORMAT(t3.previous_LNG_emission,'N2'), '; total LNG: ', FORMAT(t3.total_LNG,'N2'), '; total LNG emission: ', FORMAT(t3.total_LNG_emission,'N2'), '; Variance in LNG emission ', FORMAT((t3.previous_LNG_emission - t3.total_LNG_emission - t3.total_LNG),'N2'))
    end as fuel_LNG_emission_check
from (
    select *,
        lag(t2.total_HSFO_emission) over (partition by t2.car_carPlate order by t2.Report_DateTime_UTC) as previous_HFO_emission,
        lag(t2.total_LSFO_emission) over (partition by t2.car_carPlate order by t2.Report_DateTime_UTC) as previous_LSFO_emission,
        lag(t2.total_VLSFO_emission) over (partition by t2.car_carPlate order by t2.Report_DateTime_UTC) as previous_VLSFO_emission,
        lag(t2.total_MGO_emission) over (partition by t2.car_carPlate order by t2.Report_DateTime_UTC) as previous_MGO_emission,
        lag(t2.total_MDO_emission) over (partition by t2.car_carPlate order by t2.Report_DateTime_UTC) as previous_MDO_emission,
        lag(t2.total_co2_emission) over (partition by t2.car_carPlate order by t2.Report_DateTime_UTC) as previous_co2_emission,
        lag(t2.total_no2_emission) over (partition by t2.car_carPlate order by t2.Report_DateTime_UTC) as previous_no2_emission,
        lag(t2.total_LNG_emission) over (partition by t2.car_carPlate order by t2.Report_DateTime_UTC) as previous_LNG_emission
    from (
        select t1.id, t1.car_carPlate, t1.car_carName, t1.Report_DateTime_UTC,t1.Report_Type_Desc, t1.Master_Report_ID,
            t1.total_HFO, t1.total_HSFO_emission,
            t1.total_LSFO, t1.total_LSFO_emission,
            t1.total_VLSFO, t1.total_VLSFO_emission,
            t1.total_MGO, t1.total_MGO_emission,
            t1.total_MDO, t1.total_MDO_emission,
            t1.total_co2, t1.total_co2_emission,
            t1.total_no2, t1.total_no2_emission,
            t1.total_LNG, t1.total_LNG_emission,
            ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t1.car_carPlate order by t1.Report_DateTime_UTC desc) as RN
        from (
            select t.id, t.car_carPlate, t.car_carName, t.Report_DateTime_UTC,t.Report_Type_Desc, t.Master_Report_ID,
                sum(COALESCE(t.FuelType_HFO, 0)) as total_HFO, avg(COALESCE(t.HSFO_emission_ton, 0)) as total_HSFO_emission,
                sum(COALESCE(t.FuelType_LSFO, 0)) as total_LSFO, avg(COALESCE(t.LSFO_emission_ton, 0)) as total_LSFO_emission,
                sum(COALESCE(t.FuelType_VLSFO, 0)) as total_VLSFO, avg(COALESCE(t.VLSFO_emission_ton, 0)) as total_VLSFO_emission,
                sum(COALESCE(t.FuelType_MGO, 0)) as total_MGO, avg(COALESCE(t.MGO_emission_ton, 0)) as total_MGO_emission,
                sum(COALESCE(t.FuelType_MDO, 0)) as total_MDO, avg(COALESCE(t.MDO_emission_ton, 0)) as total_MDO_emission,
                sum(COALESCE(t.FuelType_co2, 0)) as total_co2, avg(COALESCE(t.co2_emission_ton, 0)) as total_co2_emission,
                sum(COALESCE(t.FuelType_no2, 0)) as total_no2, avg(COALESCE(t.no2_emission_ton, 0)) as total_no2_emission,          
                sum(COALESCE(t.FuelType_LNG, 0)) as total_LNG, avg(COALESCE(t.LNG_emission_ton, 0)) as total_LNG_emission
            from (
                select d.id, d.car_carPlate,
                    d.car_carName, d.Report_DateTime_UTC,d.Report_Type_Desc, d.Master_Report_ID,
                    c.FuelType_HFO, d.HSFO_emission_ton,
                    c.FuelType_LSFO, d.LSFO_emission_ton,
                    c.FuelType_VLSFO, c.VLSFO_emission_ton,
                    c.FuelType_MGO, d.MGO_emission_ton,
                    c.FuelType_MDO, d.MDO_emission_ton,
                    c.FuelType_co2, c.co2_emission_ton,
                    c.FuelType_no2, c.no2_emission_ton,       
                    c.FuelType_LNG, c.LNG_emission_ton
                from DailyReport d
                left join DailyReport_Consumption c
                    on d.Master_Report_ID=c.Master_Report_ID
                where d.Report_DateTime_UTC BETWEEN '2024-05-01' AND '2024-05-31'
                --d.Report_DateTime_UTC between DATEADD(day, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                    and d.Deleted <> 1
                    and c.master_report_id LIKE '%EFOB%'
                ) t
                group by t.id, t.car_carPlate, t.car_carName, t.Report_DateTime_UTC,t.Report_Type_Desc, t.Master_Report_ID
            ) t1
        ) t2
        where t2.RN<3
    ) t3
where t3.RN=1
)

SELECT
    82 AS Check_Number,
    'Check the inconsistency of fuel consumption' AS Check_Description,
    car_carName AS carName,
    car_carPlate AS carPlate,
    NULL AS Calendar_Date,
    Report_DateTime_UTC AS DateTime_UTC,
    Report_Type_Desc AS Report_Type_Desc,
    id,
    Master_Report_ID AS Master_Report_ID,
    NULL AS GrossTonnage,
    NULL AS Cargo_Onboard_Ton,
    NULL AS Volume_Onboard_m3,
    NULL AS Engine_Type,
    CASE
        WHEN Fuel_Type = 'fuel_HSFO_emission_check' THEN 'HSFO'
        WHEN Fuel_Type = 'fuel_LNG_emission_check' THEN 'LNG'
        WHEN Fuel_Type = 'fuel_co2_emission_check' THEN 'co2'
        WHEN Fuel_Type = 'fuel_no2_emission_check' THEN 'no2'
        WHEN Fuel_Type = 'fuel_LSFO_emission_check' THEN 'LSFO'
        WHEN Fuel_Type = 'fuel_MDO_emission_check' THEN 'MDO'
        WHEN Fuel_Type = 'fuel_MGO_emission_check' THEN 'MGO'
        WHEN Fuel_Type = 'fuel_VLSFO_emission_check' THEN 'VLSFO'
    END AS Fuel_Type,
    Total_Consumption AS Total_Consumption,
    Emission AS Emission,
    NULL AS Previous_Total_Consumption,
    NULL AS Sulphur_Content,
    NULL AS NOX_Emission,
    NULL AS SOX_Emission,
    NULL AS CO2_Emission,
    Previous_emission AS Previous_emission,
    NULL AS Previous_DateTime_UTC,
    Miscellaneous AS Miscellaneous
FROM
    FuelCheckResults
UNPIVOT
    (Miscellaneous FOR Fuel_Type IN (
        fuel_HSFO_emission_check,
        fuel_LSFO_emission_check,
        fuel_VLSFO_emission_check,
        fuel_MGO_emission_check,
        fuel_MDO_emission_check,
        fuel_co2_emission_check,
        fuel_no2_emission_check,
        fuel_LNG_emission_check
    )) AS UnpivotedResults
UNPIVOT
    (Emission FOR Fuel_Type IN (
            total_HSFO_emission,
            total_LSFO_emission,
            total_VLSFO_emission,
            total_MGO_emission,
            total_MDO_emission,
            total_co2_emission,
            total_no2_emission,
            total_LNG_emission
    )) AS UnpivotedEmissionResults
UNPIVOT
    (Previous_emission FOR Fuel_Type IN (
        previous_HFO_emission,
        previous_LSFO_emission,
        previous_VLSFO_emission,
        previous_MGO_emission,
        previous_MDO_emission,
        previous_co2_emission,
        previous_no2_emission,
        previous_LNG_emission
    )) AS UnpivotedPrevEmissionResults
UNPIVOT
    (Total_Consumption FOR Fuel_Type IN (
            total_HFO,
            total_LSFO,
            total_VLSFO,
            total_MGO,
            total_MDO,
            total_co2,
            total_no2,
            total_LNG
    )) AS UnpivotedConsumptionResults

However, I am met with the following error:

The column 'Fuel_Type' was specified multiple times for 'UnpivotedResults'.
Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 190
The column name "Fuel_Type" specified in the UNPIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the UNPIVOT argument.

*Same error message for all the UNPIVOT lines
Visually, this is the issue I'm facing:
Current Output:
| ID | Total_HFO | Total_HSFO_Emission | Previous_HFO_Emission | Fuel_HSFO_Emission_Check | Total_LSFO | Total_LSFO_Emission | Previous_LSFO_Emission | Fuel_LSFO_Emission_Check |
|----|-----------|----------------------|------------------------|---------------------------|------------|----------------------|-------------------------|---------------------------|
| A  | 0         | 1                    | 2                      | Invalid                   | 1          | 1                    | 2                       | Valid                     |
| B  | 1         | 1                    | 2                      | Valid                     | 2          | 2                    | 4                       | Valid                     |

Desired Output:
| ID | Fuel_Type | Total_Consumption | Emission | Previous_Emission | Miscellaneous |
|----|-----------|-------------------|----------|-------------------|---------------|
| A  | HSFO      | 0                 | 1        | 2                 | Invalid       |
| A  | LSFO      | 1                 | 1        | 2                 | Valid         |
| B  | HSFO      | 1                 | 1        | 2                 | Valid         |
| B  | LSFO      | 2                 | 2        | 4                 | Valid         |


Which dbms are you using? (The above SQL is product specific in several ways.)

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

General advice, take smaller steps (don't write a huge query without verifying during the process).
